# SIM900A Module doesn't send SMS to user anymore, after previously working

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to make a hydroponics project that collects data from sensors and sends it to the user through SMS every 15 minutes. However, when I try to run tests now, the pump part of the code works perfectly fine but the earlier part of the code that deals with sending the SMS doesn't work. I've tested the sim module by itself and it works, so it's not a hardware problem. What seems to be the problem here?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <OneWire.h> 
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <GravityTDS.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 5
#define DHTPIN 7     
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define TdsSensorPin A1
#define PUMPPIN 11

SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 10);
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
GravityTDS gravityTds;
Servo myservo;

char msg;
char call;

void setup()
{
  mySerial.begin(9600);   // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module  
  Serial.begin(9600);    // Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor (Arduino)
  dht.begin();
  
  sensors.begin();
  
  gravityTds.setPin(A1);
  gravityTds.setAref(5.0);
  gravityTds.setAdcRange(1024);
  gravityTds.begin();
  
  myservo.attach(PUMPPIN);
}

void loop()
{  
  const unsigned long SECOND = 1000;
  const unsigned long MINUTE = 60*SECOND;
  const unsigned long HOUR = 60*MINUTE;
   
  delay(30L * SECOND);
  int h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float tdsValue = 0;
  float temperature = t;
  gravityTds.setTemperature(temperature);  
  gravityTds.update(); 
  tdsValue = gravityTds.getTdsValue();  
    
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); 

  
  
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
  delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+************\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile number
  mySerial.print(h);// The SMS text you want to send
  mySerial.print("% humidity, ");
  mySerial.print(t);
  mySerial.print(" degrees Celsius air temperature, ");
  mySerial.print(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
  mySerial.print(" degrees Celsius water temperature, ");
  mySerial.print(tdsValue,0);
  mySerial.print(" ppm");
  
  delay(100);
  mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
  delay(1000);

  myservo.write(0);   //Clockwise maximum speed rotation
    delay(30L * SECOND);
  myservo.write(90);  
  delay(15L * MINUTE);
}
```

Comment: You might want to [edit] out your phone number

Comment: maybe you forgot to pay your cellphone bill ... test the SMS function without any of the other code

Comment: I've checked the module itself and it still sends, so the SMS module by itself cans till send text messages.

Comment: When you do `AT+CMGS="+xxxxxxxxx\r"`, you are supposed to wait for the acknowledge return by the module, it will shows a prompt `>`, only then you can send the message out. If you don't do that, add a delay(1000) after the `AT+CMGS` line. You basically send the data prematurely.